# Invalid conversion from class 'A' to class 'B'

Tags: c++, oop

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 class A
 {
    public:
    virtual void fun()
   {
      cout<<"in class A";   
   }
 };
 class B: public A
 {
    public:
    void fun()
   {
      cout<<"in class B";   
   }
 };
 int main()
 {
     B *b1;
     A a1;
     b1  = &a1;
     b1->fun();
 }
```

I get the error as

> invalid conversion from 'A' to 'B'

I am using the virtual function in the base class.
I am creating the pointer to class B and storing the address of the object
A in class B object and trying to call the function in class B.

I am using devc++ IDE.

Comment: In your example every B is an A, but not every A is a B. So the conversion B->A is OK, A->B is not OK.

Comment: cast it.  either with one of c++ fancy casts or a c stylepointer cast.  Remember to what's actually inside your "class" when you do though!

Comment: Please specify what output are you expecting?

Comment: Can you please explain how every B is a A?

Comment: I am just experiment with this whether i can store A in B and B in A. but i couldn't understand why i can't store A in B.

Comment: public inheritance describe a "is-a" relationship, which is not symmetric. For example: Woman : public HumanBeing. All the Woman are HumanBeing, but not all the HumanBeing are Woman. So, you can always safely cast the derived class to the base (call upcasting) but not the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

With your current implementation of the A and the B class, the below method will work perfectly fine.

```
 main()
 {
     B b1;
     A *a1;
     a1 = &b1;
     a1->fun();
 }
```

The reason being, A is the parent, and B is the child. Let's keep in mind the encapsulation property of OOPs, which tells us that a class contains the variables and functions enclosed as a single entity.

Now, A is an entity that contains a function named "fun". let's call it funA for avoiding confusion. And B contains all the variables and functions of A by inheritance and also contains another function "fun", let's call it funB.

Now, when you try to do A = B, i.e. trying to put the reference of an object of 'B' inside an 'A' type variable, it will not give an error, because the 'A' knows the memory structure or variables which are inherited from 'A' and exists inside the 'B' type object.

However, the B = A will not work because inside the 'A' type object, the 'B' reference won't be able to find the variables and functions which should have been there. (Because B is the child of A and would contain extra variables and functions).

Hope that clears it up.

Comment: But sir In the above code you did A = B and it did not gave error when i do B = A it gives error.